# LUIS shared authoring key

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Is there any way we could have an Authoring Key not tied to a specific user? We have a series of scripts that are updating our models. If the Authoring Key is tied to someone's account and they reset the key without notifying, our scripts would break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently. But you can create another/new account and add it as a collaborator. Then make sure this account isn't changed.

Comment: Unhappily accepted this one. A bit hacky. :) We got into a scenario where my Authoring Key went over the monthly limit because of the automation and now I can't even access the LUIS UI.